# Can't see certain folders/files in storage (FTP)

Tags: ftp, directory

I m trying to edit and fix a website's several errors, but when i m looking for the folders or files I need I can't see them. 
E.g.: -When the link is "www.somewebsite.com/facebook" i can see the facebook folder and the sub folders/files iside once I connected to the storage with FTP.
-But when the link says "www.somewebsite/rainbow/file.php" I can't see the rainbow folder (or "www.somewebsite/file.php" and I can't see the file.php inside the root folder).

I've already allowed/ticked the hidden files to show at the settings and the FTP show hidden files as well.

Is it possible that I am missing some other routing or linking?
Or it is just that the server admin didn't set the rights for every folder?

Comment: There may be a rewrite rule in a `.htaccess` file or config file.

Comment: Since I don't have admin privileges I don't have access for the .htaccess file :(

Comment: You were right about the .htaccess. The server administrator said there is this line in the file: # Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT].
(But I still can't find the source files)